# Pentaho 4.8 - Importando um Schema (Cubo)

Tags: xml-schema, pentaho

Estou usando o Pentaho 4.8 com o Saiku, e gostaria de saber como eu configuro um cubo (arquivo xml criado no Schema Workbench).

Anteriormente eu estava utilizando o Pentaho 5, nele bastava eu adicionar o Datasource e o Analysis no DataSource Manager, mas no Pentaho 4.8 estou tendo dificuldade.

Comment: Gostaria de entender o downvote nessa pergunta considerando que [perguntas relacionadas a BI](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1410/4751) tem uma ótima aceitação como *on-topic*.

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se entendi bem a pergunta, mas imagino que o que estejas dizendo é que no Pentaho 5 é possível fazer o upload do XML, e não estás conseguindo isso no 4.8, estou certo?

Supondo que seja o que eu entendi.

Antes da versão 5 do Pentaho era necessário preparar o ambiente para só depois conseguir publicar as soluções criadas no Pentaho Schema Workbench (PSW). Para conseguir fazer isso, faça:

### Etapa 1: Preparando o ambiente BI Server:

a) Pare seu servidor (se estiver no ar)

b) Abra o arquivo `publisher_config.xml` que está dentro uma sub-pasta do Pentaho BI Server: `pentaho/biserver-ce-4.8.0/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/publisher_config.xml`

c) Adicione a sua senha de publisher:

```
<publisher-config>
    <publisher-password>AQUI_VAI_SUA_SENHA_DE_PUBLISHER</publisher-password>
</publisher-config>
```

d) Reinicie seu servidor.

### Etapa 2: Usando o PSW para publicar o xml mondrian.

a) Com o seu PSW já aberto vá em File -> Publish.

b) Na tela que se abre, informe a URL do BI Server, a senha de publisher (que 
foi configurada na etapa anterior) e usuário e senha de acesso ao Pentaho.

c) Se logou certinho, já na próxima tela você poderá escolher a qual datasource o XML que estás publicando estará relacionado, e poderá escolher a pasta que será guardado o xml.

### Etapa 3: Testando.

a) Agora é só ir ao BI Server, e testar o cubo que você publicou em qualquer ferramenta de analise que tenha, seja jPivot, Saiku.